# Replace multiple parts of a string where it matches a key in an arrayList

Tags: java

New to java. I have a list of strings in my matchedStr arrayList which are keys. And I have a string[ ] in finalList arrayList which are lines of strings that contain keys as part of the text. finalList needs to be replaced with the key value when I look up a hashMap. 
The forloops seem to not amend the whole string in String[ ] finaList. Instead they amend 1 key value pair then the next on a new line losing the initially update key value.

```
ArrayList < String > matchedStr = this.regexMatcher(id, kd);
for (String[] fL: finalList) {
 for (String match: matchedStr) {
  //System.out.println(match);
  if (kd.containsKey(match)) {
   String updatedList = fL[1].replace(match, kd.get(match));
   System.out.println(updatedList);
  }
 }
}
```

How do I ensure that updatedList keeps memory of the previously updated key when doing the next key value?
i.e 1,2,3 and 4 must be updated to their values from the keys

This car costs 1 with discount of 2

This car costs 3 with discount of 4

Keys

1 = one hundred

2 = five percent

3 = two hundred

4 = two percent

Comment: You need to save `updatedList` somewhere, currently you only print it to stdout.

Comment: Trying to save it to an Arraylist but not quite working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList < String > matchedStr = this.regexMatcher(id, kd);
for (String[] fL: finalList) {
 String updatedList = fL[1];
 for (String match: matchedStr) {
  //System.out.println(match);
  if (kd.containsKey(match)) {
   updatedList = updatedList.replace(match, kd.get(match));
   System.out.println(updatedList);
  }
 }
}
```